# System.Threading.ThreadStateException Usando OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar un dialogo para conseguir un path mediante el OpendFileDialog, pero me salta la excepcion `System.Threading.ThreadStateException`.

La aplicacion es una `WebAplication`, albergada en un servidor. Por lo tanto, el PDF se tiene que generar en un directorio local del usuario que esta utilizandolo. Para ello quiero conseguir el `Path`deseado.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
private string nombreFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofg = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult rst = ofg.ShowDialog();
    string n = "";
    if (rst == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        n = ofg.FileName;
    }
    return n;
}
private void imprimir()
{
    string nomF = nombreFile();

    string nombre = nomF + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
    doc.Open();
    //GENERAMOS EL CONTENIDO DEL PDF
    doc.Close();
    //Imprimimos el doc
    Process prc = new Process();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = nombre;
    prc.Start();
}
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es que el `nombre` que se le pasa al `Process` sea el `nomF`, path generado mediante el `nombreFile()` pero me salta esa excepcion.

Comment: Buenos dias @Pikoh , no, no estoy usando threads. Simplemente necesito que el usuario pueda seleccionar el archivo donde se va a crear cierto PDF, con iTextSharp, y a este pdf tengo q pasarle el Path. para ello quiero utilizar el `OpenFileDialog`. pero me salta esa excepcion. Tendria que crearlo en un metodo aparte y luego pasarle el `String`?

Comment: Ok, Edito la pregunta en un sec para que sea mas comprensible @Pikoh

Comment: nada, sigue saliendo la misma excepcion. Tengo que instanciar el objeto de alguna manera para que no salte? esque nunca he utilizado este objeto. Y en la mayoria de la documentacion no sale nada de instanciarlo ni del threads ni nada por el estilo

Comment: Sigo sin ver en ese código que puede estar provocando esa excepción. Estás seguro que es el OpenFileDialog? Yo acabo de pegar tu codigo en una app de prueba y funciona perfectamente...

Comment: @Pikoh pues yo he generado un boton aparte para ir haciendo pruebas y sigue saltando la excepcion

Comment: Acabo de leer que es WebAplication? Entonces no es windows forms!

Comment: No puedes usar el `OpenFileDialog`de windows forms en una asp.net

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaah :( Perdon :( ya decia yo.... Y algun objeto parecido que pueda utilizar?

Comment: Pues no soy experto en asp.net,aunque diría que normalmente se usa por ejemplo un control `FileUpload`. De todas maneras, lo que quieres hacer no creo que sea posible. Desde el navegador, por cuestiones de seguridad, no se tiene acceso al disco del cliente...

Comment: ya me imaginaba yo algun tema de eso... Pero los jefes son los jefes... y tienden a darle a un mono el trabajo de un ciborg :(

Comment: Esas cosas normalmente se solucionaban con ActiveX o Flash. Dos tecnologias en extinción precisamente porque los fallos de seguridad son extremos :)

Comment: yaya, he leido algo sobre eso... La jefa dice que ellos mediante OracleForms lo hicieron... pero yo soy un yogurin recien salido del ciclo y me qieren hacer hacker o algo hahahaha